# I'm trying to install Ubuntu 20.04, but I keep getting errno 5

Tags: boot, system-installation, 20.04, crash, ubiquity

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 20.04, but I keep getting Errno 5.

Before the installation began, Ubuntu checked the files on my flash drive and it found errors in 7 files. I was  getting this error

```
The installer encountered an error copying files to the hard disk:

[Errno 5] Input/output error

This is often due to a faulty CD/DVD disk or drive, or a faulty hard disk.  
It may help to clean the CD/DVD, to burn the CD/DVD at a lower speed,   
to clean the CD/DVD drive lens (cleaning kits are often available from  
electronics suppliers), to check whether the hard disk is old and in   
need of replacement, or to move the system to a cooler environment.
```

After getting this error, I'm asked to send the bug to the developer database, after which I get to try a desktop session. I also tried installing Ubuntu from the desktop session, I got this message after selecting *Normal installation*:

```
ubi-partman crashed
*ubi-partman failed with exit code 10. Further information may be found in /var/log/syslog. Do you want to try running this step again. 
.*
```

All I did was downloaded the ISO again, used Rufus to make my flash bootable and voila! I keep getting errors. It also wiped my Windows, so for the time being my laptop doesn't have an operating system on its hard disk.

Comment: Either your downloaded ISO was flawed (did you verify it? (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0) or the write to your install media was faulty (thus the 7 errors you reported telling you not to trust your installation media for installs), and subsequent IO/squashfs errors.  You need to return to validating your ISO pre-write, and/or write it again.

Comment: Assuming you validated the ISO and it worked (I provided one link prior comment, but it'll depend on where you downloaded it do as to best link), the write to media is where I have the most problem, so I'll add https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/create-a-bootable-usb-stick-on-ubuntu/14011
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/create-a-bootable-usb-stick-on-windows/14020
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/create-a-bootable-usb-stick-on-macos/14016   Note: there are multiple types of ISO files, and some programs work with only some types... so method matters

Comment: Just adding what worked for me when this error came up. I was using a (probably cheap) SD card and USB adapter that came with my 3d printer for the boot disk, and it kept giving Errno 5. I went to the store and bought a USB 3.0 flash drive, and using that instead, installation went smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on my intel NUC that had been running flawlessly for 4 years but crashed recently and then I had to reinstall UBUNTU. I tried swapping USB drives, hard disks and ISO files - none of them worked. Once I removed one of the DRAM sticks (Micron 4GB PC3L-12800S), magically the installation worked beautifully. So bad DRAM can cause the big issue - if I had just simply removed this bad DRAM stick, it could have worked without all the troubles.